# Get the name of Actor who collided with another actor

Tags: python, pgzero

I am trying to make a simple game with a square going up and down in Pygame Zero, but I couldn't use any if statements. I am wondering what alternatives do I have for

```
if player.y>downLimit or player.y<upLimit
```

If possible, I needed a way to see the list or the name of actor who has collided with the player actor, in string form.

I have tried using jump tables, but I can't seem to use it to see the values of the player.y.

Comment: What do you mean "couldn't use any if statements"? I'd suggest providing a reproduction of that specific issue, but it really sounds like a debugging problem for you to handle.

Comment: Please provide some details about what you want to achieve and why.

Comment: The tag for [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is [tag:pgzero]